# Write array to phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, addrange

I have a following array and need to write into excel using phpexcel
I can directly write the array to excel.

```
array(9) {
  [0] =>
  array(4) {
    'hostname' =>
    string(7) 'Dibeesh'
    'hostemail' =>
    string(14) 'xxx@xx.in'
    'hostcity' =>
    string(12) 'Kochi, India'
    'host' =>
    string(4) 'host'
  }
  [1] =>
  array(4) {
    'inviteename' =>
    string(5) 'Test1'
    'inviteeemail' =>
    string(12) 'xxx@xx.in'
    'inviteecity' =>
    string(12) 'Kochi, India'
    'invitee' =>
    string(7) 'invitee'
  }
  [2] =>
  array(4) {
    'inviteename' =>
    string(8) 'Nishanth'
    'inviteeemail' =>
    string(18) 'xxx@xx.com'
    'inviteecity' =>
    string(5) 'Aluva'
    'invitee' =>
    string(7) 'invitee'
  }
  [3] =>
  array(4) {
    'inviteename' =>
    string(9) 'Lal Mohan'
    'inviteeemail' =>
    string(10) 'xxx@xx.in'
    'inviteecity' =>
    string(12) 'Kochi, India'
    'invitee' =>
    string(7) 'invitee'
  }
  [4] =>
  array(4) {
    'inviteename' =>
    string(6) 'Mahesh'
    'inviteeemail' =>
    string(14) 'xxx@xxx.com'
    'inviteecity' =>
    string(10) 'Tvm, INdia'
    'invitee' =>
    string(7) 'invitee'
  }
  [5] =>
  array(4) {
    'hostname' =>
    string(9) 'Lal Mohan'
    'hostemail' =>
    string(10) 'xxx@xx.in'
    'hostcity' =>
    string(12) 'Kochi, India'
    'host' =>
    string(4) 'host'
  }
  [6] =>
  array(4) {
    'inviteename' =>
    string(6) 'Arshad'
    'inviteeemail' =>
    string(13) 'xxx@xx.in'
    'inviteecity' =>
    string(12) 'Kochi, India'
    'invitee' =>
    string(7) 'invitee'
  }
  [7] =>
  array(4) {
    'inviteename' =>
    string(5) 'Joyal'
    'inviteeemail' =>
    string(12) 'xxx@xx.in'
    'inviteecity' =>
    string(12) 'Kochi, India'
    'invitee' =>
    string(7) 'invitee'
  }
  [8] =>
  array(4) {
    'inviteename' =>
    string(7) 'Dibeesh'
    'inviteeemail' =>
    string(14) 'xxx@xx.in'
    'inviteecity' =>
    string(12) 'Kochi, India'
    'invitee' =>
    string(7) 'invitee'
  }
}
```

How can I write this to excel using phpexcel?
Please help me to write to excel in following format
[image: ExcelFormat]

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You can write an array to a worksheet, using the worksheet's `fromArray()` method.

```
/**
 * Fill worksheet from values in array
 *
 * @param   array     $source      Source array
 * @param   mixed     $nullValue   Value in source array that stands for blank cell
 * @param   string    $startCell   Insert array starting from this cell address as 
 *                                    the top left coordinate
 * @param   boolean  $strictNullComparison   Apply strict comparison when testing 
 *                                              for null values in the array
 * @throws PHPExcel_Exception
 * @return PHPExcel_Worksheet
 */
```

e.g.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray(
    $myArray,
    NULL,
    'A2'
);
```

Though the array need to reflect the rows and columns that you're writing to, so your array will (as it stands) write 9 rows of 4 columns each.... if you want 3 rows from your array written to each row in your Excel, then you'll need to reorganise you array to match that